# Android PopupWindow not changing position after calling update()

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

My Android app has a game map with markers on it. When the user taps a marker, I'm displaying a PopupWindow aligned with the map marker (similar to Google Maps).  The problem I'm having is if a marker is close to the top of the screen, the PopupWindow overlaps with the ActionBar (and under the status bar, if the marker is high enough).

I'm displaying the PopupWindow by calling showAtLocation(), which I'd hoped would constrain the view to inside the "Map" fragment (it does on the left and right sides), but that's not working.

I had already implemented an adjustment, to account for text inside the popup taking up more than one line, where I update the Y position of the popup after the View has been laid out.  That worked with no problem, but when I tried to add another vertical adjustment for this situation, the PopupWindow's position does not change.

Here is the code for the PopupWindow implementation:

```
/**
 * Displays a PopupWindow.
 */
public class MyPopupWindow extends PopupWindow
{
    private Fragment m_fragment;
    private int m_x;
    private int m_y;

    /**
     * Displays a PopupWindow at a certain offset (x, y) from the center of fragment's view.
     */
    public static MyPopupWindow createPopup (Context context, Fragment fragment, int x, int y)
    {
        // Create the PopupWindow's content view
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from (context);
        View popupView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.view_map_popup, null);

        MyPopupWindow popupWindow = new MyPopupWindow (popupView, x, y);

        popupWindow.m_fragment = fragment;

        popupWindow.showAtLocation (fragment.getView (), Gravity.CENTER, x, y);

        return popupWindow;
    }

    private MyPopupWindow (View view, int x, int y)
    {
        super (view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;

        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.lblMapPopupTitle);
        title.setText ("Exercise Title");

        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.lblMapPopupDescription);
        description.setText ("Exercise Description\nSecond Line\nThird Line\nFourth Line\nAnd one more...");

        view.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
        view.addOnLayoutChangeListener (layoutChangeListener);
    }

    // If the tapped map location is too close to the edge, determine the
    // delta-x and delta-y needed to align it with the PopupWindow

    private int getHorizontalAdjustment (int popupWidth)
    {
        int horizontalAdjustment = 0;

        int parentWidth = m_fragment.getView ().getWidth ();
        if ((parentWidth / 2) + m_x + (popupWidth / 2) > parentWidth)
        {
            horizontalAdjustment = parentWidth - ((parentWidth / 2) + m_x + (popupWidth / 2));
        }
        else if ((parentWidth / 2) + m_x - (popupWidth / 2) < 0)
        {
            horizontalAdjustment = 0 - ((parentWidth / 2) + m_x - (popupWidth / 2));
        }

        return horizontalAdjustment;
    }

    private int getVerticalAdjustment (int popupHeight)
    {
        int verticalAdjustment = 0;

        int parentHeight = m_fragment.getView ().getHeight ();
        int y = m_y - (popupHeight / 2);

        if ((parentHeight / 2) + y + (popupHeight / 2) > parentHeight)
        {
            verticalAdjustment = parentHeight - ((parentHeight / 2) + y + (popupHeight / 2));
        }
        else if ((parentHeight / 2) + y - (popupHeight / 2) < 20)
        {
            verticalAdjustment = 20 - ((parentHeight / 2) + y - (popupHeight / 2));
        }

        return verticalAdjustment;
    }

    private View.OnLayoutChangeListener layoutChangeListener = new View.OnLayoutChangeListener ()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange (View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom)
        {
            int height = bottom - top;
            int width = right - left;

            // Adjust the y-position for the inflated height of the view
            // (so the popup's bottom edge lines up with the tapped marker's top edge)
            int y = m_y - (height / 2);
            int x = m_x;

            // Determine any adjustments that need to be made to line up the tapped marker with the popup
            int horizontalAdjustment = getHorizontalAdjustment (width);
            int verticalAdjustment = getVerticalAdjustment (height);

            y -= verticalAdjustment;

            // Update our position with the re-calculated position
            update (x, y, -1, -1);

            view.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
}
```

The issue can be seen in this screenshot: [PopupWindow overlaps ActionBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWiT7.png)

Basically, I need to either (1) get the PopupWindow to clip to the Fragment's view and not overlap the ActionBar, or (2) get the PopupWindow to update its position in the event that it *does* overlap the ActionBar.

Any help is greatly appreciated.